# Create c# soap certificated service in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap, ssl-certificate

Anyone know an example (host and client using wsdl) in c# (for Visual studio) to create a SOAP service with certificate (.pfx) for a MVC.

I use IIS selfcertificate to create the host

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use SOAP?

Comment: The "token" approach is a little post-SOAP. WCF will let you use client certificates. WCF tutorials are a-plenty.

Comment: It´s client compulsory to use SOAP and wsdl, that´s the problem to find a an example

Comment: From the first google on "c# wsdl wcf" : https://zblesk.net/blog/how-to-create-a-wcf-web-service-from-a-wsdl/

Comment: I need Web Service in ASP.NET(in MVC)  not a  WCF Service

Comment: You can add (Add New Item) a WCF service to any ASP.NET project. Or an ASMX service. But I think WCF is better. But working WSDL-first means you can forget about click-Next wizards. Start up your  Cmd Window.

Comment: Yes, I added a service .asmx and import his wsdl reference, but the problem is to have some kind of secure login for the client before return a result from service. I need an example, I tried a lot of tutorials but I cannot solve it. More times I can´t do in the client something like: MyServiceReference sr = new MyServiceReference ();

Comment: "to have some kind of secure login" is not answerable.

Comment: As I see now, the only real secure form is with certificate ( .pfx)